# Clearance gem not displaying flash messages (Ruby on Rails 5.0.1)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, clearance

How do I display flash messages when using the `clearance` gem for user authentication?

I have this code set in my `view/layouts/application.html.erb` inside the body tags:

```
<% flash.each do |key, value| %>
  <div class="alert alert-<%= key %>"><%= value %></div>
<% end %>
```

I have checked the docs and wiki but couldn't find anything. When I create a user or login/logout there is no flash message displayed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clearance does not display success flashes for sign in or sign out as the success of these actions isn't deemed to be notable and alert-worthy.